# extracting a <div> value out of a website using lua

Tags: lua

I want to get a  value out of a website.

I want to get the `ARS$ 3.435,63` out of this div and put it into a varible to calculate with.

```
<span class="market_commodity_orders_header_promote">ARS$ 3.435,63</span>
```

I have searched up some stuff but couldn't find anything to help me so if anybody know how to to this in lua that will be nice.

note: I am intermediate at lua

I have not tried "luasocket" because the download page is gone

Comment: Try `print(s:match("^.->(.-)<"))`.

Comment: instead of "searching up some stuff" you should probably just read the Lua manual?

Answer (score 0):

To download a webpage using only the lua standard library, you can call `curl` if your system has it installed.

```lua
-- Download webpage
local file = assert(io.popen("curl site.name.com", "r"))
local htmlText = assert(f:read("*a"))
file:close()

-- Find commodity cost
local _, _, cost = htmlText:find("<span class=\"market_commodity_orders_header_promote\">(ARS\$ [0-9.,]+)<\/span>")
print(cost) -- Should print "ARS$ 3.435,63"
```